# Issues with inline plots and widgets after Anaconda installation on windows 7 workstation

Tags: matplotlib, windows-7, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I can't get inline plots or widgets to show properly on either Jupyter (5.5.0) notebook {[Issues withing Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJsd6.png)} on Internet Explorer, or using the QtConsole(4.3.1) {[Issue within QtConsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3oi1.png)}. I have installed Anaconda (Navigator 1.8.7) on a Windows 7 machine. This a shared high-performance workstation PC.

I initially thought that it was a file access/reference issue given that there are multiple user accounts on the PC and mine isn't the admin account (although I do have admin access), and so I uninstalled my first installation of Anaconda (same version 1.8.7) for my individual account and reinstalled it for all users. However, this didn't solve the problem.

The Matplotlib plots do show up correctly when I use spyder, if that helps with debugging. But I would really like it if it worked on Jupyter.

Apologies if there isn't enough information here. Will update as suggested. Appreciate the help.

Here's some additional information about the conda version: [Conda Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihV8t.png)

Comment: To show figures inline you need to use the inline backend which can be activated via `%matplotlib inline` in jupyter/Ipython. For the widgets make sure you have enabled them as shown in [the installation docs](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html#installation).